# resizableImageWithCapInsets: resizingMode: UIImageResizingModeTile isn't working

Tags: objective-c, image-resizing

UIImage's `resizableImageWithCapInsets` method is all well and good for a standard rectangular button with rounded corners, but I'm trying to create a button that looks like a cloud, with uneven edges. I can't quite get my head around the best way to draw or create it, or how I'll stretch it when I get it into my application. I'm talking about something like this:

[image]

The bubbles on the sides of the cloud shouldn't stretch, but new ones will be created for however long / short the button needed to be. For example, if the button needed to be half the size of this image, only 2 of the bubbles would be shown, but if it needed to be taller, more than the 5 here could be, it'd add and remove them as necessary. I'd set minimum sizes so that at least one bubble would always be there, preventing issues if it got too small. The bubbles themselves can be tiled if need be.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can achieve such an effect, either from the perspective of software development or graphic design?

**EDIT:**

I've tried to do this with the image below and the following code, and it's giving a result like the image here. The image isn't even the right size, let alone tiling. I've verified that the frame of the image is larger than its being displayed here, too. Really rather confused here!

`cappedCloud = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"cloud.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(9, 9, 9, 9) resizingMode: UIImageResizingModeTile];`

```
[[cell.cloudButton imageView] setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
[cell.cloudButton setImage: cappedCloud forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.cloudButton setAlpha: 0.85f];
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If that is the issue you are seeing, then something must be wrong with the way you are applying the image, can you include the code for how you are setting the image on that UI element?

Comment: There you go. The `ScaleToFill` is something I was just trying now, didn't make any difference :(

Comment: Ok, the problem seems to actually be that you are trying to set the image for a button, I've taken your image and made it tile in an imageview, looking into how to get the resizing to work correctly for the button

Comment: I've made a separate question and a separate project not using buttons, just a `UIImageView`, and am having the same issue. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252408/tiling-a-uiimageview-using-resizeableimagewithcapinsetsresizingmode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to look into how to create a [tiled resizable image](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) using

```
- (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets resizingMode:(UIImageResizingMode)resizingMode
```

Using a slightly modified version of your code, I was able to get the image to tile on a button, although it doesn't tile very well:

```
UIImage* cappedCloud = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"cloud.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(9, 9, 9, 9) resizingMode: UIImageResizingModeTile];

[cloudButton setBackgroundImage:cappedCloud forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cloudButton setAlpha: 0.85f];

cloudImage.image = cappedCloud;
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like `UIImageResizingModeTile` is only available in iOS6.

Comment: @lukech So it is, in which case, maybe someone has some code for how to draw a tiled image pre-iOS6, but your problem is definitely resolved by tiling, not stretching

Comment: Could you go into a little more detail on how I'd actually make that happen? I only really know of tiling as just taking the whole image and repeating it over the given area, that's not what I want to do here. The documentation has very little mention of the tiling option.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no built-in tiling resizing option pre-iOS6, but try searching around for "tiled resizable image in iOS5" or whatever your target OS version is

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't really answer my question. I'm asking whether you could explain how tiling works in conjunction with cap insets. Does it tile the middle of the image, and re-attach the capped parts to the outside afterward, or something similar? I've been able to find next to no other examples of this.

Comment: "The image is tiled when it is resized. In other words, the interior region of the original image will be repeated to fill in the interior region of the newly resized image."  That is a direct quote from the documentation

Comment: So what happens to the caps while it's stretched? Are they tiled too?

Comment: The caps are always drawn exactly as they appear in the original image

Comment: Right, but if you've expanded the image, how can they be? If my source image is 100x100 and I stretch it to 300x300, the middle tiles, fair enough, I get that, but what happens to the edges?

Comment: Try this link: http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/ios-5-uiimage-and-resizableimagewithcapinsets.html Visuals make understanding this easier

Comment: I've seen that example before, but again I'm afraid it doesn't answer my question. If I specify caps at 10, 10, 10, and 10, tile mode will tile the area inside those caps, but that still doesn't explain what happens to the areas outside of them. They need to be made larger somehow to cover the larger image size, I'm asking what will happen? I've edited the question showing the issue I'm having, if that's any more help.

Comment: I edited my answer, it seems that `UIButton` images are not resized, and therefore it will not tile, but the background image is

Comment: Gah, confusing! But that did it, thankyou very much for sticking with me there!

Answer (score 0):

Stretching is processed in the vertical direction and then in the horizontal direction (or vice versa). So provide top & bottom offsets considering vertical direction that should not stretch and left & right offsets for horizontal direction.